# How can I defense from attackers who send junk data packet?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, packet

I wrote a TCP socket program,and define a text protocol format like: "length|content",

to make it simple, the "length" is always 1-byte-long and it define the number of bytes of "content"

My problem is:

when attackers send packets like "1|a51",it will stay in tcp's receive buffer
the program will parse it wrong and the next packet would start like "5|1XXXX"，
then the rest of the packets remain in the buffer would all parsed wrong，

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get garbage, just close the connection. It's not your problem to figure out what they meant, if anything.

Comment: for example , attack A send "1|a51",then user B send normal packet"4|haha",now the buffer contains "1|a514|haha" , but the packet A just send mess it out ,program would receive it in this way:first packet:"1|a" , second packet:"5|14|ha" , 14|ha become the content...

Comment: A and B can't send data on the same connection, unless your threat model is much wider than just junk packets, in which case you should have said so in your question. You can use SSL to defend against that.

Answer (score -1):

instead of length|content only, you also need to provide a checksum, if the checksum is not correct, you should drop the connection to avoid partial receive.
this is a typical problem in tcp protocol, since the tcp is stream based. but just as http, which is an application of tcp protocol, it has a structure of request / response to make sure each end of the connection knows when the data has been fully transferred.

but your scenario is a little bit tricky, since the hacker can only affect the connection of his own. while it cannot change the data from other connections, only if he can control the route / switcher between your application and the users.

Comment: What about garbage with a correct checksum? This just moves the problem, it doesn't solve it.

Comment: no, checksum is also useful in this scenario, it can help you to detect the partial receive. while what eliriclzj mentioned is, you even cannot detect whether it's a garbage. and in the scenario eliriclzj mentioned in the reply. 1. attacker A will not be able to use the same connection with user B, only if they are coming from the same client. 2. if they are using the same client, the checksum will help you.

Comment: A checksum doesn't protect you against garbage with a correct checksum. It may have many virtues but it isn't the answer to the question.